# Equality with Double.NaN

Tags: c#, equality, nan

I have the following code...

```
if (Price_Foreign != Double.NaN)
{
   output.Append(spacer);
   output.Append(String.Format("{0,-10:C} USD",Price_Foreign));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
NaN USD
```

What gives?

I'm using Double.NaN to indicate that the value doesn't exist, and shouldn't be output.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the `IsNaN` static function?

Try something like this:

```
if (!Double.IsNaN(Price_Foreign))
{
   output.Append(spacer);
   output.Append(String.Format("{0,-10:C} USD",Price_Foreign));
}
```

Comment: Does ‘is NaN’ test correctly for C#7 pattern matching? if (`xxx is Double.NaN`).

Answer (score 39):

The [IEEE 754 floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) states that comparing NaN with NaN will **always** return false.  If you must do this, use `Double.IsNaN()`.

But, this isn't the best way to do what you're trying to do.  Doubles are NOT precise, and you're using them to represent prices here.  I'm betting that at some point, you're going to want to compare prices for equality, too.  That's not going to work, because [you can't rely on floating point equality](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

You should really look into using some integer type for these values (that supports equality comparison) rather than trying to use doubles.  Doubles are for scientific problems; not for finance.

Comment: See comment to original question. -- I'm stuck with an existing database from years back.

Answer (score 10):

`Double.NaN` is not equal to anything, not even itself.

See the [Double.NaN Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(VS.71).aspx) in the .NET Framework Class Library documentation:

> Use [IsNaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.isnan(VS.71).aspx) to determine whether a value
>   is not a number. It is not possible to
>   determine whether a value is not a
>   number by comparing it to another
>   value equal to NaN.

Comment: Unless you use `.Equals`!

Answer (score 8):

As background information: what the `IsNaN()` method does is `return v != v;`

Comment: No. See [Reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,b3843db5f359a0fd)

Comment: I tested this: IsNaN() DOES work, while comparison does not.

Comment: @cskwg Test again, or prove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy, like me, you can use the following extension method:

```
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
public static bool IsNaN( this System.Single v ) {
    return System.Single.IsNaN( v );
}
```

You would need another one for System.Double.